# Create table in HIVE from CSV semicolon delimited data

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveddl

I am new to HIVE and this is my first take on it

This is a sample of my data

> age;"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y"
> 58;"management";"married";"tertiary";"no";2143;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";261;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
> 44;"technician";"single";"secondary";"no";29;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";151;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"

I tried creating the table using the below command:

```
create external table bank_dataset(age TINYINT, job string, education string, default BOOLEAN, balance INT, housing BOOLEAN, loan BOOLEAN, contact STRING,day STRING, month STRING, duration INT,campaign INT, pdays INT, previous INT, poutcome STRING,y BOOLEAN)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;'
location '/user/user_name/Bank_Project';
```

I create the table then whatever queries i run on it (other than select * from table) yields an error.

I assume it has to do with the ";" between the data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, terminated by is the issue in some hive version like Asure. Pls use `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0059'` instead of ';'.

```
create external table bank_dataset(age TINYINT, job string, education string, default BOOLEAN, balance INT, housing BOOLEAN, loan BOOLEAN, contact STRING,day STRING, month STRING, duration INT,campaign INT, pdays INT, previous INT, poutcome STRING,y BOOLEAN)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0059'
location '/user/user_name/Bank_Project';
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Pls note, on higher hive versions, `'\u003B'` may work. Unicode code point for semicolon (;) is `U+003B` so second solution makes more sense. But i think hive assume 0059 as decimal and interprets to ';'.